# Suspending an initialisation thread that executes an external method for prolonged period

Tags: java, android

Due to the deprecated nature of the Thread stop() and suspend() methods, I have become accustomed to implementing a standard cooperative suspension method using the well tested wait/notify methodology. Unfortunately my current project includes an initialisation thread that duplicates a recursive directory structure via a single call to an external method that doesn't return until it has finished and does not implement any kind of wait/notify cooperation.

I'm curious to know what other programmers are tempted to do in this situation,  save perhaps reimplementing the external method, as I'm quite tempted to use the Thread.suspend() method and hope the file operations contained within the external method don't hold on to anything critical whilst suspended.

Hmmm...this is a tricky one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well do not even try `stop()` or `suspend()`. They were deprecated and there are reasons for rightly so. Ideally you shouldn't even be trying `wait` or `notify` when you have so many excellent libraries available in [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.

In your case, you should check the documentation of the external method you are calling to know about the shutdown policy of that library. If none is mentioned then you can probably try interrupting. interrupt will surely work if the external method call makes some blocking calls. Other than it, I see no other way.

Using `suspend` will only lead to instability rather than aiding anything. Not using it will take more computational power but will be stable atleast.

Comment: I can guarantee the external library call does not make blocking calls as I wrote it some time ago...no worries, I was looking for a quick fix where there really isn't one :) You're quite right of course; using Thread.suspend() is a quick hack that will end up causing more trouble than its worth. I'll rewrite the external code in order to make it Thread friendly. Thanks again for your input...I needed someone to talk some sense into me before I made a really poor decision. Marked as answered.

Comment: In the interest of documenting this post as best I can, Java's deprecated Thread methods {e.g. Thread.stop()} appear to be a moot point within this context as Android throws an OperationNotSupported exception in order to prevent their use.